# MVVM: Dependency Injection and creating ViewModels on demand

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ninject

I am strapping up a small WPF Application with MVVM and Ninject for DI (for the first time).

Creating my "Single Instance" ViewModels for the static UI Elements is easy going. But I am struggling with the ViewModels which are created on demand, e.g. on user actions, which cannot be injected, but have to be created - somehow- in the class itself.

The easiest way would be injecting the Ninject Kernel or make it globally available, but I believe thats bad practice.

While searching for a solutions, I strumbled on these two:

- ViewModelLocator: I think it is more for the "Single Instance" ViewModels and because I am using DataTemplates to hook up the ViewModel with the View (ViewModel first), I am feeling its not the right way, but maybe I will integrate it for my singletons (if it does make sense with using WPF DataTemplates?).
- Factory Pattern: I read about using an Abstract Factory for Object creation and just injecting the Factory into the ViewModels, which then can use it to create the dynamic ViewModels on demand. Sounds pretty easy and thats why I am in doubt, if its just relocating the problem?

So basically I am trying to get an Instance of an ViewModel Object by the Ninject Kernel deep down in the ViewModel Tree, e.g. triggered by an user event.
Because I am using an Event Broker for Ninject, the Event Broker is only hooked up for Objects created by Ninject. Thats why I need my ViewModels created/injected by Ninject.

Comment: So your question is what exactly? Do you need advice? The Factory Pattern is very valid!

Comment: Yes, I need an advice which way to go.

Comment: You either `new InnerVM()` yourself if `InnerVM` has not many dependencies or you `InnerVMFactory.Create()` it, which is cleaner. Your `OuterVM` will then have a dependency on `InnerVMFactory`.

Comment: OK, thats what I imagined. And that the Factory has a dependency on the Ninject Kernel is totally valid?

Comment: no, the factory does not have a dependency on the Ninject Kernel. The Factory does the `new InnerVM()`. Its dependencies are whatever Dependencies `InnerVM` has and it provides these to the `InnerVM` in every `Create()`

Comment: what I described is the bare bones approach. the exact way a DI framework supports the factory pattern differs. For NInject you might want to take a look [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki/Factory-interface)

Comment: OK, but by using the constructor itself, and not Ninject, I still have the problem to hook it up (the new ViewModel) to the Event Broker and resolving this dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117299/discussion-between-markus-hutter-and-jdeuker).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with the factory pattern.
The factory itself should then be part of the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) as Mark Seemann describes it.

To make things simple you can use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory).

Comment: So I created a Factory for my ViewModels using Ninject.Extensions.Factory. Implemented my own `IInstanceProvider`, which depence on the `IEventBroker`. The InstanceProvider is used by the Factory. All hooked up in the composition root. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you inject the factory in your main viewmodel and pass it around to create sub viewmodels deep down your viewmodel tree?

Comment: @Wouter: Not completely. All ViewModels are created by Ninject, the whole tree. The Nodes, which will create new ViewModels, will have a dependency on the factory, so Ninject will inject it. So I have not the work to pass instances down, everything is strapped up in the composition root.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Prism](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPhMTx0vLNAhWGPxoKHURFDlQQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprismlibrary.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFuJxpRKAW9ZEOlIjIO3Fs53VpIJg&sig2=mqGKoBAUDHB0OZHCUme_6g) a rather big MVVM framework extensively. It is built around dependency injection and it provides a class ViewModelLocator that automatically searches for the `ViewModel` type that should be injected into a `View` when it is instantiated. Internally it uses a static service locator, but you don't need to worry about it.

```
<UserControl x:class=".."
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

Brian Lagunas, one of the maintainers of Prism has a [nice writeup](http://brianlagunas.com/getting-started-prisms-new-viewmodellocator/). Note that even though Prism is huge and provides loads of features you don't need to use everything.

Comment: I like the idea of a ViewModelLocator Class, where I could mock up ViewModels for design purpose. But as I mentioned I also like the convenience of DataTemplates to hook up my ViewModels to Views. I think its not possible to use both patterns together?